# Can my Nikon D70 take video?

Tags: nikon, video, nikon-d70

Having an older camera (which is my Nikon D70) is there any possible way to make it take photos and videos or is it impossible, I don't mind installing anything new on to it aswell.

Comment: So you bought a camera without even knowing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible, I'm afraid. Video is just so much of a fundamental change that there's no way a manufacturer, or anyone else, could add it to a camera by a firmware update or similar even if they wanted to.

Comment: I guess in some cases you could (as a manufacturer or skilled hacker) - but without a lot of testing you could quickly get into the situation where you wear the camera out very quickly (it needs to be designed to deal with the mirror being up a long time often without burning out a solenoid ... to have a constant CPU load for minutes without overheating sh....)

Answer (score 0):

The Nikon D70 has a composite video out port.  It appears that this is only for displaying what would be on the camera's display, and since the D70 doesn't do LiveView, you aren't going to get "videos" per se, although you could get NTSC/PAL "video" of photos playing back.